# Updatepanel in usercontrol driving me crazy

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I've build a pager to enable pagination for a repeater control. The page structure looks like this:

MasterPage
 -> Page
    -> Dynamic usercontrol
       -> Dynamic usercontrol with repeater inside updatepanel

Now what I'm trying to do is just a simple updatepanel.Update() procedure but it's just not working. When debugging I see everything get's loaded fine, current page index, data collection...it's all there but i see no changes in browser.

Funny thing is when i remove the updatepanel everything works as expected. And when I copy everything to another page (including updatepanel) it all works fine too.

Now I figure it might have something to do with the dynamic loading of the control but have no clue what since everything is there and seems normal, just no refresh in page.

Does someone have encountered similar problems?

Thanks again!
Mark

Comment: Oh yeah, i'm using asp.net 4.0 with webforms

Comment: And the control get's added in Page_Init event

Comment: me and me comments....I'm making use of asp.net routing too, but I don't think thats  the problem but I'm not sure of anything atm!

Comment: Hint: Edit your questions and add extra info there instead of adding comments. Question: Can you post the Html of your page and any code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out, I had a response.write somewhere on the containing page. Yeah I know it's bad but didnt want to debug all time ;p